# How to change a model property from a javascript function inside a view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model

Is there any way to alter my Model properties from a javascript function inside a view?

Specifically, I have an edit view and need to access a string property value with

> function SomeJSFunction() { 
>      var somevar = '<%=Model.Property %>'; 
>   ...

then do some changes on somevar and set the model property to the changed string.
I'm doing a submit at this point, so it's not a question of dealing with the display, just need to alter the model from inside the function before I submit. I know I could pass the string as a parameter and deal with it inside the controller but it just doesn't cut it as I really need to be done with it in the view. Appreciate any help!

Comment: i don't think you can change what is already in the ViewModel - i believe this is read-only. Why don't you set a hidden field in the form (from javascript), then you can look at that in the Request.Form collection when you submit?

Comment: yes, it is read-only. think of the model as being a 'served' response. once it's written to the page, the response is over. it's not like the bound controls in webfroms that talk to the page life-cycle. you'll have to 'post' the changes back via either a .net form or via jquery ajax etc.. this is basically how mvc works, so there's plenty of stuff out there to reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this using javascript. The model is instantiated by the controller and passed to the view. If you want to modify some properties you will need to perform a request to a controller action and send the new values. This could be done either using a standard form or AJAX request.

Comment: OK that clarifies it for me. Thanks a lot!