# Set the model property in MVC using the javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#

There is a scenario where I want to update the Model with which the `.cshtml` page is binded, using javascript. I do not want to use the `document.getElementById`.

Can we achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: you can get the element by class, or by name or using general JQuery libraries

Comment: I don't want to use the class or id , can we get the model object in the javascript?

Comment: Without additional information (for example) your current code, its hard to tell exactly what you are asking here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access model in javascript asp .net mvc razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391402/access-model-in-javascript-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Comment: You can only read it in javascript but you can't edit it. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3914069/924810)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, instead of `document.getElementById` you could use

```js
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Comment: This is how to get the model to the javascript, Now if i will change variable model data then will it reflect on screen?